# Associated Changesets missing in Alert Email - TFS Build

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, msdeploy

We have our TFS Build set to CI:
[image]

When we Disable Label Sources we do not get associated changesets in alert email, we don't want to enable Label Sources as it creates a Label since we wanna create a Label only for Live builds
[image]
Any idea how we can achieve this?

Comment: Is there any feedback?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in the XAML build in TFS 2013, it can't be achieved.

If you set the Label to false, in the build, you will get an warning:

> Cannot associate changesets and work items because the current build
>   was not labeled.

So there's no associate changesets in your alerts notifications if a build is not labeled.

This has been optimized in [Vnext build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/get-started/dot-net). You could upgrade to TFS 2015 or upper version. Then using VNext build. When you don't label in the build definition, it could also associate changesets and workitems.

Comment: that's helpful to know its not possible in TFS2013, we will enable Label sources for now and later update to newer version of TFS. Thanks.